# PHP fatal error - Call to a member function prepare() on resource

Tags: php, sql

I have looked at other questions but i can't see a link between mine and others issues so i was wondering if i could get some advice on where i am going wrong.

I read about not mixing API's but im not sure if i am or not?

**submitNoteText.php**:

```
?php include 'connectionDetails.php'; ?>

<?php


if (isset($_POST['noteid1'], $_POST['notetext1'])) 
{
    var_dump($_POST['notetext1']);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Notes SET Note = ? WHERE NoteID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $notetext2, $noteid2);

    $noteid2 = $_POST['noteid1'];
    $notetext2 = $_POST['notetext1'];
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();
}
else
{
    if (isset($_POST['notetext1'])) {
        var_dump($notetext2);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Test";
    }

}


?>
```

**connectionDetails.php**:

```
<?php
$myServer = "test ip";
$connectionInfo = array('Database' => 'DiscoverThePlanet', 'UID' => 'Test', 'PWD' => 'Test');

//connection to the database
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $connectionInfo)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//Test connection to server
// if ($conn) 
// {
//     echo "connection successful";    # code...
// }

?>
```

The error is in the **submitNoteText.php** and is this line:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Notes SET Note = ? WHERE NoteID = ?");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sqlsrv_*` API doesn't have a `prepare()` method. You're mixing database APIs.

Either use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) or use [sqlsrv_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, in the documentation in the params i can't figure out what the int is for, they use a number 1 in the params what is this for? Ignore me it is a parameter xD

Comment: This is working and there are no errors, just getting a 504 time out error when i send the Ajax post now, not sure if thats related to this php query, thanks for your answer though!

Comment: @user7409253 It could be related, *maybe* during the connection to the database. If you can figure out where the timeout is happening in the application (ie: the ajax request connecting to the server, the application connecting to the database, etc) open a new question if you don't know how to fix/debug it `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You are calling variables before you declare them

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Notes SET Note = ? WHERE NoteID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $notetext2, $noteid2);

$noteid2 = $_POST['noteid1'];
$notetext2 = $_POST['notetext1'];
```

Switch order to

```
$noteid2 = $_POST['noteid1'];
$notetext2 = $_POST['notetext1'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Notes SET Note = ? WHERE NoteID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $notetext2, $noteid2);
```

Ok, i just noticed :

you are calling :

`$conn->prepare()`

but $conn is not instance of PDO. You are mixing api. Change your $conn according to docs:
http://php.net/manual/pl/pdo.construct.php

Comment: Thanks for answer however it's still saying the same error on that prepare line

Comment: Thank you, i believe the guy above just got there first though, but your answer is appreciated none the less!

Comment: Yeah, I was editing mine answer when he popped up :D